# How to input multiple arguments in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

My contract has a function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool), I want to run this function in remix injected web3 env.
I wanted to transfer 100 tokens of this contract https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xf63acf73c90b1136a39e5e64f839b68b808f7be7#code

How do i enter the parameters in remix? I tried "0xaddress",100000000000000000000 (that is 100  * 1e18) and it gave me this error

transact to RTTToken.transfer errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed

However if i try "0xaddress",100 it manages to transfer but then i am only getting 1e-15 token transferred which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, big numbers should be entered between quotes as if they were strings.

Try with "0xaddress", "100000000000000000000"